# Is there any way to not show occurrence events when I call Microsoft Graph api - CalendarView with delta function

Tags: office365, microsoft-graph-api

I tried to get incremental changes to events in Office 365 Calendar service, and I follow this document to send the Graph CalendarView api.

https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/delta_query_events

The server responded a lot of occurrences of a recurring events which is repeated everyday without end.
However, the only thing I care about is the changes of recurring events and its exceptions.

Is there any way to get the changes to event but not show occurrence event?

Comment: Are you saying they _always_ show up in the delta or that any change to the `event` (Master, Occurrence, Exception) triggers _all_ of the related `event` instances to surface in the delta?

Comment: Yes. After I modify a master event, the server responses the master event I changed and all of related occurrence events. I have some master events which are repeated forever. If I change them, I will get a lot of changes from CalendarView api. It's so inconvenient. Is there any way to filter out 'occurrences' event?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could subscribe to the `events` collection instead of the `calendarview`. With the `events` collection, you don't get recurrence expansion.

So something like `/me/events` or `/me/{calendar-folder-id}/events`.

Comment: Ok. I see. Thanks for your explanation.

Answer (score 0):

If an `event` Master is edited, it will automatically cascade those changes to every occurrence/instance of that `event`. You cannot filter out these events, and more importantly, in practice you really wouldn't want this behavior.

If there is a change to the recurrence pattern, the attendees, or any number of other properties then you would *expect* a notification. The API simply notifies you whenever a change has been made. It has no way of knowing which "change" your application might care about.